# writing xml file with xercesc::DOMWriter

Tags: c++, xml, xerces

I am trying to write a xml file using xercesc::DOMWriter in c++.
But I get a compilation error when writing the line:

```
xercesc::DOMWriter *theSerializer = ((xercesc::DOMImplementationLS*)impl1)->createDOMWriter();
```

**error: DOMWriter is not a member of xercesc**

I have the following includes:

```
#include <xercesc/util/TransService.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOM.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMAttr.hpp>
#include <xercesc/parsers/XercesDOMParser.hpp>
#include <xercesc/framework/LocalFileInputSource.hpp>
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use macro `XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_USE` to import symbols from Xerces's namespace to global namespace.

Alternatively, you can use `XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE::`

Comment: So, your code should be: `DOMWriter *theSerializer = ((DOMImplementationLS*)impl1)->createDOMWriter();`

Comment: And XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_USE immediately after headers inclusions.